# If marker.setMap == null do something

Tags: google-maps-api-3, null, conditional-statements, marker

I want to implement something by Google maps and I need to know if setMap is alreay set or is null. How can I implement something like this:

```
if (marker.setMap == null)
{
    marker.setMap(map);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to call the getMap function, not check if the setMap function is null.  This will toggle the marker:

```
if (marker.getMap() == null) marker.setMap(map);
else marker.setMap(null);
```

or even

```
if (!marker.getMap()) marker.setMap(map);
else marker.setMap(null);
```

Comment: And what about other shapes. For example circle, rectangle, polygon and et cetera?

Comment: Same concept applies, if they have getMap and setMap methods (which they do).

Comment: Sure they do.  Where are you having an issue?  That would be a topic for another question though.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that, because `marker.setMap` **removes** the reference to the map.
Instead, use `marker.setVisible(false)` to hide your marker, then, simply test visibility of your marker. `setVisible` just hides the marker, but the reference to the map is not lost.